# Alfresco node locking in a web script

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, alfresco

What I am trying to do is create a set of alfresco web scripts that will allow me to interact with the files in my webproject. I manage to make all the operations of a normal filesystem (list, edit, delete, rename, etc) but i have a huge problem with the lock mechanism. Once someone edits a file in his own sandbox the file must be locked.

Now in the listing of the files, i have access to a method called isLocked() that tells me if a node is locked or not and I can see the owner of the lock as well. These locks were added from the Alfresco default web interface.

And to my question, how can I lock/unlock a node from the a web script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no Javascript bridge to the [`LockService`](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/lock/LockService.html), meaning you need to develop a [Java-backed Web Script](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/topic/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/concepts/ws-folderListing-JavaBacked-create.html?resultof=%22java%22%20%22web%22%20%22script%22%20). You will be then able to do something like:

```
LockStatus lockStatus = lockService.getLockStatus(node);
if (LockStatus.LOCKED.equals(lockStatus) ||
    LockStatus.LOCK_OWNER.equals(lockStatus)) {
  lockService.unlock(node);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't touch the alfresco in any other way beside installing my webscripts

Comment: Then you're not going to remove locks from web scripts. I was able to unlock content using a WebDAV client ([cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/)), but I have no idea if WebDAV works with the old WCM repository (AVM) which seems what you're currently using (and that's also been deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do two things:

1) use the Check-in/out Javascript API [Wiki location](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#Check_in.2FCheck_out_API). If a document is checked-out it will get locked and put in Read-Only mode. And the user can check it in, when he's done.

2) use a [Java Backed Webscript](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java-backed_Web_Scripts_Samples) with pure Java, you have more control on it. You can lock, unlock etc.

Comment: the checkin/checkout doesn't lock/unlock the file. and it creates a new file and appends to the file name the string "(Working copy)".

Comment: It puts the file in read-only for everyone, so I don't know your use-case. But it's mostly sufficient. And of course there is a difference locked and read-only. But in similar use-cases both can be applied.